# How can I get component state change in another component with litElement?

Tags: typescript, custom-component, state-management, lit-element, lit-html

I started a project based on [LitElement](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/) 
There are many components nested in each other, Let us say we have this structure:

[image]

the root component is `my-app`

```
import { LitElement, html, customElement, query } from 'lit-element';
import './my-form';
import './my-view';
import { MyView } from './my-view';

@customElement('my-app')
export class MyApp extends LitElement {
  @query('my-view') private myView?: MyView;

  private handleCountChange(e: CustomEvent<{ count: number }>) {
    if (!this.myView) throw 'my-view not found!';
    this.myView.count = e.detail.count;
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <my-form @countChanged=${this.handleCountChange}></my-form>
      <my-view></my-view>
    `;
  }
}
```

as you see we have two components: my-form

```
import { LitElement, html, customElement, property } from 'lit-element';

@customElement('my-form')
export class MyForm extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: Number }) count: any = 0;

  private updateCount(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.count = (<HTMLInputElement>e.target).value;
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('countChanged', {
        composed: true,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        detail: { count: this.count }
      })
    );
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <input value=${this.count} @input=${this.updateCount} type="text" />
    `;
  }
}
```

and my-view:

```
import { LitElement, html, customElement, property } from 'lit-element';

@customElement('my-view')
export class MyView extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: Number }) count: number = 0;

  render() {
    return html`
      <p>${this.count}</p>
    `;
  }
}
```

To get the property `count` changes from `my-form` into `my-view` I dispatched event listener then used it at `my-app` then at `handleCountChange` I'm assigning the `count` value to `MyView` which imported as a class in addition to import it as a componet.

Currently, this works, but I feel it is a long way especially when I have more nested components. I would like to know if there is a better for doing that. 
Is there something similar to `Context API` which exists at `react.js`
I thought about using `redux` but somebody didn't recommend it with litElemnt.
One of the ideas I'm thinking is to dispatch the event to `document` instead of the current component, but maybe this is a bad practice! What are your suggestions, please let me know?

Comment: "somebody didn't recommend it with litElemnt" You should use the tools that make sense for you. Redux seems like a reasonable approach. The [PWA Starter Kit](https://pwa-starter-kit.polymer-project.org/overview) is built with LitElement and uses Redux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have probably resolve this issue, but I can send you how I would deal with this.

You need to lift your state up to your `my-app` component. This state will be a single source of truth and deliver `count` value to `my-form` and `my-view` child components.

In `my-app` component, you can change `handleCountChange` to something like this (in case, if you define `count` as an attribute and let `my-app` to receive initial value from attributes):

```js
 private handleCountChange(e: CustomEvent<{ count: number }>) {
   this.setAttribute('count', count); // If you set `count` as observed attribute, you will not need to call `requestUpdate` method
 }
```

or like this, if you define `count` as class property

```
 private handleCountChange(e: CustomEvent<{ count: number }>) {
   this.count = count;
   this.requestUpdate(); // force to call render method which is necessary in this case
 }
```

Note that, you will have to send `count` value also to the `my-form` component. It will work also without it, but if you will do it, you will lost single source of truth of your state and that can cause potencional unexpected behaviour.

If you will need to send an example, please let me know.